# Web components in Angular’s template-driven forms

Tags: angular, web-component, shadow-dom

I am using web components from an external library brought into my Angular 6 application.

These web components are using Shadow DOM.

Are there any best practices for using web components inside of a template driven form in angular?

I’ve tried:

```
<my-text-input [(ngModel)]=“model.name” name=“name” id=“name” ngDefaultControl [ngModelOptions]=“{standalone: true}”></my-text-input>
```

This at least binds the initial rendering of the form to the model. I actually see the model.name (Dr IQ, in this case) in the input, however, once I begin typing, I am not seeing the model update.

I have a feeling this has something to do with e.target.value not coming from the input element inside of the web component, but the actual custom element itself. This means that the value is not truly updating and keeps sending out undefined or an empty string.

I hope this question makes sense and appreciate any answers! shadow DOM and events (at least target within events) has been proving to be a little frustrating, especially when it comes to the value property.

Comment: a web component can not be a custom control component (a custom control component must extends from ControlFormAntecesor). In your case "divide" the ngModel or use the "properties" of the component. < my-text-input #id1 [value]="model.name" (change)="model.name=id1.value/> or  < my-text-input [ngModel]="model.name" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" >